# How to make searches more natural?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Having documents with `Name` and `Description` fields.
`Name` having more weight `Description`

I want to get documents ordered by score like this:

1. Exact match
2. Partial match
3. Fuzzy match
4. Fuzzy Partial match
5. Proximity terms score higher.

I'm doing this surgery to get something similar to what I want:

```
public Task<DocumentSearchResult<T>> SearchWithFuzzyAsync<T>(string searchTerm, SearchParameters sp) where T: class
{
sp.SearchMode = SearchMode.All;
sp.QueryType = QueryType.Full;
searchTerm = Sanitize(searchTerm).Trim();
var keywordTrimmedFuzzy = searchTerm.Replace(" ", "~ ");
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
{
    return Task.FromResult(new DocumentSearchResult<T>());
}
var searchTerms = $"({searchTerm}) 
        || ({keywordTrimmedFuzzy}~) 
        || ({keywordTrimmedFuzzy}*)^0.8";
return indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync<T>(searchTerms, sp);
```

Am I missing something or should I construct this type of thing to get some decent results?

The problem I see with this approach is that I cannot let my users use the search engine to it's full extent (like having the option to use - or advanced syntaxes) unless I manage on my code.

Wouldn't it be easier if you could do something like:

```
sp.UseFuzzySearch = true;
sp.UsePartialMatch = true;
sp.ProximityTreshold = 4;
indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync<T>(term, sp);
```

instead of creating wonky search strings? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, rewriting user queries to include fuzzy and/or partial matches is the best you can do, if you don't want to expose the query language to your users.

I agree that a configurable query parser that performed some of these transformations for you would be nice. Interestingly, not many of our customers have requested it. Please create a [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/filters/top?page=1) idea to help us prioritize.

Relative importance of fields (field boosting) can be defined with [Scoring Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index). Therefore, if you want to give a higher weight to the Name field, you don't have to rewrite the search query.

Note, that wildcard and prefix queries always contribute constant score to the overall documents score, more details in the scoring section of the [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture) article.

Comment: I'm using a scoring profile (forgot to mention). What is not clear about your note is if the `^0.8` thing using here `({keywordTrimmedFuzzy}*)^0.8` is affecting the results or not.

Comment: I find it hard to imagine someone using azure search besides some simple testing not requesting this feature. Without it, if I have a title `Bart` and search for `Bar` or `Bart*` won't return that item. I don't see why the last one is by design and not a bug.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/11112582-support-prefix-matching-for-suggestions that gots 13 votes and points to a similar issue.

Comment: Hi Bart, responding to this https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/18991633-wildcard-search-does-not-return-a-full-match, If your two documents, one with Bart and one with Bartuy, if you search for Bart* both documents should be returned. Is this not what you are observing? feel free to reach out directly jlembicz at microsoft